# Tutorials for a blogging application in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, blogs

I am learning node.js, and would like to try building a blog on the platform. Do you know of any good tutorials that show you, step-by-step, how to build a blogging app on node? I have seen one by Nettuts, but it doesn't explain a full solution, with databases an the like. So are there any good tutorials? I do not mind if it is text or video, as long as it is descriptive and helpful.

Thanks for any recommendations!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, when you encounter a problem, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @PeterLyons the link is dead

Comment: @PeterLyons I'm looking to host my node app on a VPS, any thoughts on deploying a node blog to a linux server?

Comment: @pixel67 see my answer below. My blog repo includes automated deployment with Ansible/Vagrant/Bash.

Comment: @PeterLyons thanks mate, I tried signing up to be notified of new blog posts on your site, but your reader is not working.

Comment: You don't "sign up". You subscribe in an RSS reader like feedly.com or whatever. The "/feed" URL looks to be working fine.

Answer (score 4):

My blog is written in node.js and express.js. I uses just a simple git repo on the filesystem for the post content. It is open source at [github.com/focusaurus/peterlyons.com](https://github.com/focusaurus/peterlyons.com/tree/v5.0.2/app/blogs). Feel free to look around if you find it helpful and shoot me follow-up questions. It is no-frills but does have a basic post editor with preview and allows me to add custom markup processing logic.

There is a fully automated deployment solution in there coded in Ansible and bash that I use to deploy it to both a Vagrant-based staging VM and a production digital ocean droplet.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'm trying to achieve a similar setup. Thanks

Comment: What database are you using for your blogs? Where are your blogs stored?

Comment: No database, just a git repository on the filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try ExpressJS

As an ExpressJS intermediate, I can understand the question coz even I coudnt find an expressjs tutorial that "just" works and is minimal.

You can try this http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/ tutorial or the hack sparrow express tut mentioned by Wyatt

If you are completely new to MVC web frameworks, its gonna take a lot of patience. Since I worked on Django befor, I was able to stand up n run pretty quickly with ExpressJS

So even if the tutorial doesnt make sense there's plenty of other resources likes docs, google and StackOverFlow :D

Answer (score 0):

Node is all about using what is available in the ecosystem. npm is great and sets node apart from other environments. You could use, for example, [Wheat](https://github.com/creationix/wheat).

That said, you could check out [this article](http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb) which is pretty old, but good.

Alternatively, I think the [Hack Sparrow Express Tutorial](http://www.hacksparrow.com/express-js-tutorial.html) would have a lot of valuable concepts for you, especially when coupled with his posts on [Mongo](http://www.hacksparrow.com/tag/mongodb).